# View diff when improving edit

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Quite often, I see a partially correct edit in the "suggested edits" queue. Such as the editor fixing 10 grammar mistakes, but introducing other 3 at the same time. Or improving code formatting, but slightly messing up something else. I like to `Improve` such edits to fix the bad bits.

Unfortunately, once I click `Improve`, I couldn't find a way to see the edit's diff again (and the `Improve` button is scripted, so no "Open link in new tab" is possible). Finding the 3 mistakes (particularly in a long post) is pretty hard.

Am I missing a way to view the diff when improving the edit, or is there none? And if it isn't, could it be added?

Comment: Good idea. And to the best of my knowledge this does indeed not exist.

Comment: copy the url to the clipboard, open a new tab/window, paste the url, hit enter.

Comment: work around != solution

Comment: This would also be great when making suggested edits in the first place, for those of us with less than 2K rep. I remember seeing a feature request for that, too, although I can't find it at the moment.